# set header in middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to set a header in a middleware to avoid Google bot for indexing something like a login page. And I actually made it work but came across this error which I cannot understand.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    $next($request)->header('x-robots-tag', 'none', false);

    return $next($request);
}
```

The code above won't add this header `x-robots-tag: none` while the below code does.

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    $response->header('x-robots-tag', 'none', false);

    return $response;
}
```

Isn't it basically the same thing? The only difference is putting `$next($request)` in a variable or not. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's walk through the second version:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request); //You get the Response instance and store it

    $response->header('x-robots-tag', 'none', false); //you set the header

    return $response; //and then you return it
}
```

whereas

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    $next($request)->header('x-robots-tag', 'none', false);//You set the header to the response

    return $next($request);// Here you get another instance thus the previous result is lost
}
```

Imagine that `$next($request)` behaves like a factory.