# How to offer API access to only whitelisted domains using laravel passport

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport

I am working on a project, which provides API for the web application to the user, who purchases the specific package. I am using Laravel(5.7) Passport service for designing APIs.

I tried to add header in middleware and my api.php both, but it doesn't work for me.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://clientdomain.com')
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
```

I want to restrict user for single domain access only, during API authentication, and when API called from an unwanted domain I can throw an error message.

My middleware looks like -

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://clientdomain.com')
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization');
}
```

Please guide a correct approach for that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Define "doesn't work for me". What happens? Do you see the headers? Have you tried [setting the headers on the `$request` object properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000074/set-header-in-middleware)?

Comment: @ceejayoz I added middleware code in my question, by "doesn't work", I mean when I am trying to call API from another domain, that still sending the response. Please help me with the correct approach.

Comment: OK, but again, do you see the headers? Inspect the calls your browser's making via the network panel. See what's being sent, and what errors the browser outputs.

Comment: @ceejayoz This message display under Response Headers without error, when I am trying to call with localhost
`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
 Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization
 Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://clientdomain.com
 Cache-Control: no-cache, private
 Connection: Keep-Alive
 Content-Length: 11`